# WordPress Weird Margin on Product Items

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

http://snappyblue.com/

Where is this margin coming from?! I have tried doing all kinds of fixes with the styles in WordPress and nothing seems to fix the products which are list items under an unordered list. The products seem to have a great margin at the top and are ordered like a ladder. I've tinkered with it using firebug as well. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please a the snippet of code from your WordPress stylesheet (css) file. So we can see what the problem is. You can get there by going to your admin panel > Apperances > Editor. Then on that the right sidebar go to your **Style**

[image]

Comment: I cannot post the whole css stylesheet here nor do I know where the problem is coming from, if I did I wouldn't be asking this question. I provided the site and the code can be viewed from there.

Comment: No problem. It seems like you have two issues. One random <a> added which is setting off the aligment. As well as a margin top/bottom percentage. There is a photo you can use as a reference --->
[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/lSQ65MM.jpg?1)

Comment: really appreciate your answer. I don't see the extra `<a>` they all seem to have a closing tag? Also, what element or class has margin on the top or bottom?